# Aws mobile hub and asp.net web api integration is it a good design?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, asp.net-web-api, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-mobile-hub

Can we use aws mobile hub for authentication and integrate asp.net web api for other business logic is it a good design ? I want to use sql server instead of dynamodb also i am not very fimiliar with lambda functions. Any suggestiosnb

Answer (score 0):

I'm not providing a recommendation here regarding ASP.net, but I just wanted to let you know that you can use AWS RDS to host managed SQL Server instances, so you do have the option of using an architecture like...

Amazon API Gateway ->
AWS Lambda ->
AWS RDS (SQL Server)

You can find documentation on that here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html

...and more info about AWS-hosted SQL Server...
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/

And, if you want to kick the tires on hosting business logic in the cloud using Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda, you can create an API in AWS Mobile Hub, here:
https://aws.amazon.com/mobile

Comment: Andrew i am hosting our Sql database on RDS and for API I am using EC2 where my asp.net web api project hosted now my only concern is can i access cognito user details in my api project ? Am i on a right direction ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. It sounds like you have a webapp running in the browser that is making AJAX calls to your API which is hosted on EC2. Your code running on your EC2 instances can then make API calls to Cognito using the service's REST API. I'm not an expert on ASP.net or on passing through credentials in such an API, so I don't think I can help too much in this area. Here's some links that may be useful.

.NET SDK
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-setup.html

AWS .NET Developers Blog
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/category/net/

Comment: Thanks Andrew for you quick response , I will look into those documents . Just for clearification I have hosted restful api on ec2 that is consumed by mobile clients , mobile client is using cognito for authentication after authentication mobile app communicate with restful api hosted on ec2 instance. I am looking for how can i verify if user is logged in on my ec2 instance.

Comment: I talked to a solution architect who recommended you open a support ticket, so they can help get you the info you need. You may also find useful information in the AWS forums. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/category.jspa?categoryID=22